# Given number of array "distribute/scale" to specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, decimal, scale

I am working on a project in which I need to distribute the values of an array and the sum of these values must be 100.

Examples:

- `[70, 34, 92]` and the total value `100`. The output is `[35.71, 17.35, 46.94]` because `35.71 + 17.35 + 46.94 = 100`.
- `[86, 99.5, 100]` and the total value `100`. The output is `[30.12, 34.85, 35.03]`.
- `[96, 37]` and the total value `100`. The output is `[72.18, 27.82]`.
- `[98, 76.5, 68.5, 63.5, 38.5]` and the total value `100`. The output is `[28.41, 22.17, 19.86, 18.41, 11.15]` = 100(sum).

My solution so far:

- Sum all the values in the given array
- Multiply each value by 100
- Divide each value by the total sum
- use `.toFixed(2)`.

The "formula/calculation": `+(((valueOfArray * 100) / totalSumOfGivenArray).toFixed(2))`

My first solution(problems with decimals so not acceptable):

```
prioritySum  = 0;
controlsKey.forEach((value) => {
      priorityVal = this.getDistributedValue(+form.controls[formId].value, totalCatSum); // return +(((valueOfArray * 100) / totalSumOfGivenArray).toFixed(2))
      prioritySum = prioritySum + priorityVal;
});
```

This solution sometimes doesn't return exactly the 100 value. Output various such as 99.99, 99.999999, 100(mostly), 100.0000000001, 99.999978, 100.09999999, 99.000009. There are some issues with decimal numbers here.

The other approach I used is this:

```
let i = 0;
for(i = 0;  i < controlsKey.length-1; i++){
  let formId = controlsKey[i];
  relValue = this.getDistributedValue(+form.controls[formId].value, totalActualSum); // returns formula result
  form.controls[formId].setValue(relValue))
  relativeSum = relativeSum + relValue;
}
relValue = 100 - relativeSum;
form.controls[controlsKey[i]].setValue(relValue)
```

This works fine but this solution hmmm...

So my question is there any elegant solution to this problem?

The first solution is ok for me but there are some issues with decimals even I used `.toFixed(2)`

Comment: what is the question? if the last works for you, then fine.

Comment: I haven't posted my full code for this problem because it is a mess. So my question is: is there any other solution to this problem? "more elegant" solution

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is. "Distribute the values of an array" — what does that mean?

Comment: Also make sure you understand how binary floating-point math works.

Comment: scale the values of an array and after scaling the values the sum must be 100. I did some examples, maybe you can check that to understand

Comment: OK well anything you do that involves computations with fractions is liable to result in the inaccuracies you're seeing. That's the world of computer floating-point math; it's not based on decimal fractions but *binary* fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent unwanted floating point values, you could use integer values and subtract the value from a base value of `10000` (100 and two places) and create an array of strings where the dot is inserted into the value for getting formatted string.

```js
const nice = s => s.toString().replace(/\d\d$/, '.$&');

function get100(array) {
    var sum = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b),
        offset = 1e4;
    return array.map((v, j, { length }) => {
        if (j + 1 === length) return nice(offset);
        var i = Math.round(v * 1e4 / sum);
        offset -= i;
        return nice(i);
    });
}

console.log(...get100([70, 34, 92])); // [35.71, 17.35, 46.94] 
console.log(...get100([86, 99.5, 100])); // [30.12, 34.85, 35.03].
console.log(...get100([96, 37])); // [72.18, 27.82].
console.log(...get100([98, 76.5, 68.5, 63.5, 38.5])); // [28.41, 22.17, 19.86, 18.41, 11.15]
```

Comment: why base 10000? it could also be 1e10 or something else 1e3, ... right?

Comment: no, because you want 100 and with two places you get 10000 as integer value.

Answer (score 1):

So the big issue is that there is an inherent inaccuracy with floating point numbers.  If you *don't* use `toFixed` the issue impossible to resolve - even if you determine the error, and pick an element and increase/decrease it by the amount of the error, you'll simply be off by that amount in the *other* direction, since a floating point number is not capable of holding the necessary amount of precision across all of the operations:

```js
function getDistribution(values) {
    var sum =  values.reduce((carry, current) => carry + current, 0)
    var distribution = values.map(v => 100 * v / sum)
    var err = distribution.reduce((carry, current) => carry+current, 0) - 100;
    console.log({distribution, err});
    distribution[0] -= err;
    err = distribution.reduce((carry, current) => carry+current, 0) - 100;
    console.log({distribution, err});
}

getDistribution([98, 76.5, 68.5, 63.5, 38.5]);
```